# Open weather application with a specific location by pressing a button (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know if is possible to open the weather application with a specific location (ex. Berlin) already set by pressing a button

```
@IBAction func openMeteoTo(_ sender: Any) { }
```

and if there are some documentation about it or tutorials, i did a little research but i didn't find anything.

Comment: No, there is no public API to launch Apple's Weather app.

Comment: @rmaddy And if i don't want to weight the app, so just wanting to make a reference to something else with the ibaction, which alternative can be used to show the meteo of a specific location?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, iOS Weather App hasn't an URL scheme.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899) is something about other iOS URLs.

Comment: thank you, but if i don't want to weight the app, so just wanting to make a reference to something else with the ibaction, which alternative can be used to show the meteo of a specific location?